# How to "turn off" location services when a map view with no location manager disappears?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, mkmapview, cllocationmanager, location-services

I have an `MKMapView` in a view controller where I call:

```
[self.mapView setUserTrackingMode:MKUserTrackingModeFollow animated:YES];
```

When I navigate to another view controller and the one with the map view disappears, I still have the location services running (I see the arrow in the status bar). I'd like to turn it off once I'm not seeing the map anymore, but I don't know how to do this without having a `CLLocationManager`...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
   [super viewDidDisappear:animated];

   self.mapView.showsUserLocation = NO;
   [self.mapView setUserTrackingMode:MKUserTrackingModeNone animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

if ([CLLocationManager significantLocationChangeMonitoringAvailable])
    {
        if (OUTPUT_LOGS) NSLog(@"Stopped monitoring for significant changes");
        [[self locationManager] stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
    }

    [[self locationManager] startUpdatingLocation];

}


-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    if ([CLLocationManager significantLocationChangeMonitoringAvailable])
            {
                [self.locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];


            }

 [[self locationManager] stopUpdatingLocation];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the point is I don't have any `locationManager` to call its `stopUpdatingLocation` method...

Comment: -(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
   
    
    [[[CLLocationManager alloc]init] stopUpdatingLocation];
    
} try above way..

Comment: It does not seem to work, the location services arrow is still shown in the status bar...

Comment: then please create a CLLocationManager  object and set required property and add code which i have share ....

Comment: I have a location manager in another class that could be running... doesn't this cause problems? Having two concurrent location manager?

Comment: No matter, concurrent location manager indicates particular page , But other call location manager updating location continously then stop both location manager. Create a singleton call for class where have location method define, 
- (void) locationStart {
     [[self locationManager] startUpdatingLocation];
}
- (void) locationOff {
     [[self locationManager] stopUpdatingLocation];
}
call this method from other page.